# Can someone help me with the App that uses this folder string?

Tags: android, directory, subdirectory, malware, virus

I have an older Samsung tablet and going through it I found the following set of folders and have no idea which App is using this. Can anyone help me with identifying the APP? I don't know if it refers to a virus or what. Any help would be appreciated!
Best, Scott

(ExtX)/Root/media/0/.hide/…
or
(ExtX)/Root/media/Android/data/com.sec.android.app/FlashBarService/files/Pictures/…

I did many searches on the internet wasn't able to identify the App associated with this string of folders.

Comment: Through what App would files end up in this string? How would they be uploaded into it?

Answer (score 0):

The folders you've listed are located on the internal storage of your Samsung tablet, and they appear to be used by the Samsung FlashBarService app. The app provides a feature called "Smart alert" which helps you to quickly check missed calls, new messages, and other notifications by gently vibrating when you pick up the device.
The folders in the path you've provided seem to be used to store data related to this feature, such as images or other files.
It's not a virus and it's a built-in app provided by Samsung to enhance your experience with the tablet.
If you don't want to use this feature or want to free up space, you may consider disabling it or uninstalling the app.
Please let me know if you have any more doubts.

Comment: What does the ExtX stand for? The other string is not flashbarService